# parse data from xml file with java

Tags: java, xml

so i have this xml file that looks like this:

```
<inventory>
 <products>
  <product>
  <code>016-023</code>
  <desc>Gallon 2% Milk</desc>
  <quantity>10</quantity>
  <price>2.49</price>
 </product>
</products>
<transactions>
<purchased>
  <code>016-023</code>
  <count>5</count>
</purchased>
<sold>
  <code>019-011</code>
  <count>3</count>
 </sold>
 </transactions>
</inventory>
```

i need to count all the products and parse the file to get the code, desc, quantity, and price to add to a new product. i've got the creating object and adding to inventory part but cant figure out how to parse it from the file. here's what i have so far:

```
public void parse(String fileName) 
    throws SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException
{
    File f = new File(fileName);
    Document doc = builder.parse(f);

    // Count the number of products, and then get
    // the code, desc, price, and quantity for the product
    // from the document, create a new Product object
    // from the code, desc, price, and quantity, and add the
    // product to the inventory using addProduct(). 

            int invCount = Integer.parseInt(path.evaluate("count(/inventory/products)", doc));


    for (Product product : products) {
        String code = path.evaluate("/inventory/products[" + i + "]/product/code", doc);
        String description = path.evaluate("/inventory/products[" + i + "]/product/desc", doc);
        Double price = Double.parseDouble(path.evaluate("/inventory/products[" + i + "]/product/price", doc));
        int quantity =Integer.parseInt(path.evaluate("/inventory/products[" + i + "]/product/quantity", doc));

        }


addProduct(new Product(code, description, price, quantity));
```

please help me get this. thanks!

Comment: take a look at this url : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser

Comment: @esprittn i'm supposed to use XPath evaluate() method. and the xml file will have varying amount of products

Comment: updated the post and added some more code.

Comment: please add the complete code. I'm not really clear what is the `products` list is.